Ways to intercept error responses in Django and DRF
The problem:

Django errors are values to details keys.
Django Rest Framework (DRF) errors are values to detail keys.

Therefore, having an application that raises both Django and DRF exceptions is inconsistent by default. I want a way to change the response errors so that they look like this:
{
  "message": ...,
  "code": ...
}

Are there ways to handle both Django and DRF exceptions at the same time and respond with a custom response body?
I have tried:

custom exception handler in DRF, but this only handles DRF exceptions
custom error messages when defining models
  email = models.EmailField(error_messages={"required": {"message": "", "code": 123}})

but Django can't handle a dictionary as a message
Adding a DRF validator to my serializer:
email = serializers.EmailField(
    validators=[
        UniqueValidator(
            queryset=models.User.objects.all(),
            message={
                "message": "a user with this email already exists",
                "code": status.EMAIL_EXISTS,
            },
        )
    ],
)

but this does not override the response body, but instead it embeds the message as an error message to the {"details": {"message": {<embedded dictionary>}}}

The only thing I believe would work, is to try-except all exceptions inside my Views, but I would like to know if there is a prettier way than placing all my Views inside try blocks.

Have you tried middlewares?

@ChukwujiobiCanon No, my bad. I will take a look into it.
